# Declare the namespaces of xml files in the 'header' with python ElementTree

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, elementtree, xml-namespaces

I have a function which takes a number of inputs and generates some xml elements for me and for that I need a couple of different namespaces which I have defined. Problem is, when I generate the file it will always declare the namespaces in the tag I used to specify the location of where the elements should be generated. I want the declarations to happen in the first element, in my case the 'svg' element. Here is the code:

```
if not self.hasSelfHeader and not self.hasDefsHeader:
        self.outputRoot.insert(0, ET.Element(ET.QName(self.someNamespace, 'self')))
        self.selfHeader = self.outputRoot[0]
        self.outputRoot.insert(1, ET.Element('defs'))
        self.defsHeader = self.outputRoot[1]
        
    newParamDef = ET.SubElement(self.selfHeader, ET.QName(self.someNamespace, 'paramDef'))
    newParamDef.set('name', name)
    newParamDef.set('type', type)
    newParamDef.set('default', value)
            
    newLocalDef = ET.SubElement(self.defsHeader, ET.QName(self.someNamespace, 'localDef'))
    newLocalDef.set('name', 'local_' + name)
    newLocalDef.set('type', type)
    newLocalDef.set(ET.QName(self.someotherNamespace, 'value'), name)

    tree = ET.ElementTree(self.outputRoot)
    tree.write("testing.xml" , encoding='utf-8', xml_declaration=False)
```

The input I give into my program is:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 120 120" version="1.1"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle id="one" cx="60" cy="60" r="50"/>
  <rect id="two" x="0" y="0" width="10" height="20"/>
</svg>
```

The output I want to get:

```
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:ns="http:namespace.com"
    xmlns:nsbind="http:namespace.com/bind/"
     viewBox="0 0 120 120" version="1.1">
          <ns:self>
            <hmi:paramDef name="test" type="Color" default="0xFFEEEEEE"/>
          </ns:self>
          <defs>
            <ns:localDef name="local_test" type="Color" nsbind:value="{{ParamProps.test}}"/>
          </defs>
<circle id="one" cx="60" cy="60" r="50"/>
      <rect id="two" x="0" y="0" width="10" height="20"/>
    </svg>
```

And the generated output:

```
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 120 120" version="1.1">
      <ns:self xmlns:ns="http:namespace.com">
        <hmi:paramDef name="test" type="Color" default="0xFFEEEEEE"/>
      </ns:self>
      <defs>
        <ns:localDef xmlns:ns="http:namespace.com"  name="local_test" type="Color" nsbind:value="{{ParamProps.test}}"/>
      </defs>
<circle id="one" cx="60" cy="60" r="50"/>
      <rect id="two" x="0" y="0" width="10" height="20"/>
    </svg>
```

I get why it doesn't work, it cannot access the 'head' of the xml file and will therefore place the namespace declarations at the most top-level element it can find, but I just don't know how to do it differently.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add your exact expected output?

Comment: @JackFleeting Sure, done

Comment: Great. Now can you also edit the question to show the "number of inputs" used to generate the expected output?

Comment: @JackFleeting I wrote the intended output by hand and did not generate it via code.

Comment: I understand, but I still need to see what it is the input you used to create the xml.

Comment: 1) The code posted is just a fragment. Please post code that we can actually copy, paste and run ([mcve]). 2) The output that you want does not have a declaration for the `hmi` prefix.

Comment: Ok, so I edited the question again to show the used input. Sorry @JackFleeting , I didn't know what you meant on Friday. However it would take me quite a lot of time to make a minimal reproducible example of my code without copying almost 500 lines of code here. I hope the information is enough now.